# How can I change Sourcetree theme?

Tags: themes, atlassian-sourcetree

I use all my development tools in the dark theme except Sourcetree.

It has no option in its configuration to change theme.

Is there any other way to change for a dark theme?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The dark theme is working on Windows client now. My Sourcetree version is 3.2.6.

After you update your Sourcetree, you can change your theme on `Tools > Options > General > Theme > Dark`.

[image]

Comment: It's a great news. Thank's to share.

Answer (score 123):

**Mac**:

- *Newer Versions:* View > Appearance > Dark Mode
- *Older Versions:* View > Theme > Dark.

**Windows**:

- Tools > Options > General > Theme > Dark

Comment: I this also available in windows?

Comment: No, for Windows latest version is 2.1.2.5

Comment: Thanks, I get the dark theme on SourceTree 2.7.1 and macOS 10.13.3. ->
 https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Comment: It works. But their dark theme is too bad. Gitkraken's theme is much better sourcetree's.

Comment: Does not apply for windows

Comment: changed to - View > appearance > darkMode

Answer (score 13):

on Mac:
View -> Appearance -> Dark Mode

Answer (score 10):

Looks like official support is rolling out tomorrow, though you can manually download the update now. https://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2017/07/17/engineering-a-darker-sourcetree/

Comment: That's macOS only, though.

Comment: Why no option for windows?

Answer (score 10):

You can get the new version of sourcetree. It will update your old version to the new one.

Tools > Options > Updates!

OR

https://product-downloads.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/windows/ga/SourceTreeSetup-3.2.5.exe

Then, go to Tools>Options and General/Theme and select Dark

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you switch Windows to a dark theme, SourceTree will follow.

Source: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-1097

Edit: Now there is a built in solution. See Ryan's answer

Comment: I would like a more practical solution without having to change the windows theme. It's ugly. Now, we can only wait a release of a new feature.

Comment: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-2351 - Latest open issue request for a dark themed feature internal to SourceTree (1097 was closed years ago, despite currently active comments) - Follow and Vote

Comment: GitKraken is a great alternative to SourceTree if you need a dark theme. Also it is available on Windows, macOS, and Linux. Real easy on the eyes. https://www.gitkraken.com/

Comment: This answer never worked, 15 days later (or 4 comments below) it says, it doesn't work, many texts are not visible, Atlassian should fix this.

Comment: This answer is wrong and not working because it only change the colors of Windows Store Apps and since SourceTree is not a Windows Store app, it won't work for Sourcetree

Comment: @Theotonio Not only Windows Store Apps.

Comment: @NoxMortem What features are missing?

Comment: @Alex78191 at the time of writing the comment about GitKraken it had no git-lfs support, was missing a lot of information accessible with sourcetree regarding branches, logs/blame, etc. However, I have not used it since I wrote that comment and can not say anything about the current state of gitkraken

Comment: gitkraken can't do commercial use.